# Symfony 2 - datetime field with null value returning DateTime object

Tags: symfony, datetime

I am trying to check if `datetime` field is empty or `null`:

```
if (!$entity->getDate()) {
```

In database field value is `null`, but this condition fails and when I dump this date, I get:

```
object(DateTime)#1790 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(27) "-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Entity's property:

```
/**
 * @var \Datetime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="start_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $date;
```

Any ideas why field woth null value is transformed to a `DateTime` object? How to I check if `datetime` field in database is not `null`?

Comment: Copy your field entity mapping please. It should return null.

Comment: @COil done. Check it out

Comment: Did you check your field value? Also copy/paste the table schema for the field.

Comment: What does your getter function look like? How are you sure the database field value === null? You could use `is_null()` but you'll get the same results if the db value is not actually null. What you wrote should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your field contain:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

And is not null, perhaps this default value is set for your date column.

```
$date = new \DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
dump($date);

DateTime {#1336 ▼
  +"date": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Paris"
}
```